# for with if & ifelse

Tags: php, if-statement

I have 5 images named **1.png, 2.png, 3.png, `4c.png`, & 5.png**.

I want to show this images in PHP like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuLxC.png) but it shows like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAgx8.png).

My code is:-

```
<div class="row">
<?php 
$images = "/downloads/vf/images/";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++):
    if (!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$images.$i.".png"))
        
        continue; // Skip this iteration if it can't find the file 
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="<?php echo $details . $i;?>.php">
          <img src="<?php echo $images;?><?php echo $i;?>.png" alt="<?php echo $i;?>">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
<?php endfor; ?>

<?php 
$images = "/downloads/vf/images/";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++):
    if (!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$images.$i."c.png"))
        
        continue; // Skip this iteration if it can't find the file 
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="<?php echo $details . $i;?>.php">
          <img src="<?php echo $images;?><?php echo $i;?>c.png" alt="<?php echo $i;?>">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
<?php endfor; ?>

</div>
```

Can it be changed in `if`, `elseif`.

I [want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuLxC.png) but it [is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAgx8.png).

Comment: yes that is normal becase first you make a loop just for image from 1 to 5, then you make another loop for images from 1c to 5c and result is 1 2 3 5 4c

Comment: There is many ways to do that. One way would be to use glob() to list the filenames and foreach them. Another way would be to loop 1-4 then output 4c and 5 manually.

Comment: @AlivetoDie its an example, actually I am having 100 images from that many of images may contain **c.png**

Comment: In that case use glob() and sort the array how you want to output them then foreach them

Comment: @Andreas I am dull in using glob()

Comment: Yes, it may 5,6,7 or 4,5,15,....

Comment: It is not compulsory that it will be 4c.png, 8c.png, 16c.png, it may also be 5c.png, 7c.png, 8c.png

Comment: I want that all images should be shown number wise, it should not get disturbed due to **some other text after number**. I need only to be shown `1.png` then `2.png` then `3.png` then `4c.png` then `5.png` and so on...

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative Solution:**

You will always have problem, if the image names change like adding different suffix then 'c'. You do not have to care about the image names. All we need to care is that, **it always starts with number.**

> Get the image names -> convert to array -> sort -> output

Try this:

```
<?php
   //Put this part to top of your page 

   $path = "/downloads/vf/images/";

   //1. get all imagenames
   $images = array_diff(scandir($path), ['.', '..']);

   //2. sort numerically, string after the first numerical-char will be ignored
   if (count($images) > 0)
       sort($images);
   } 
?>
//3. output
<div class="row">
  <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++): ?>
    <?php if (file_exists($images[$i])): ?>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="<?php echo $details . $i;?>.php">
            <?php echo sprintf("<img src='%s%s' alt='%s'>", $path, $images[$i], $i); ?>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endfor; ?>
</div>
```

This should work for every image names like below:

```
1.png, 2.png, 3.png, 4c.png, 5a.jpg, 6x.png....n
```

Comment: best solution among all.+1. Chirag Jain  please go for it. this is the perfect solution for you. I deleted mine

Comment: I will be glad if this answer will be edited with starting <div class="row"> or else I should consider that it should be written just after <div clas="row">...

Comment: @VuralAcar Where should be written `1` & `2`? as my page doesn't start with `<?php`

Comment: What do you mean with 1& 2? Maybe I missed something

Comment: all these :- `$path = "/downloads/vf/images/";` ; 

`//1. get all imagenames
$images = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));` ; 

`//2. sort numerically, string after the first numerical-char will be ignored
sort($images);` ;

Comment: oh sorry, now I get it.. Let me change it

Comment: it says the path does not exists. You just have set the correct path to the images. you can use ``substr(__DIR__, strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));`` to find out the real relative path

Comment: So, what should I set? I have all my images at `http://localhost/downloads/vf/images`

Answer (score 0):

Change the name "4c.png" image in 4.png or follow this code

```
<?php 
$images = "/downloads/vf/images/";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++):

    if (!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$images.$i."c.png")){
        $img = $i."c";
    }

    else if (!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$images.$i.".png")){
        $img = $i;
    }
    else{
        continue; // Skip this iteration if it can't find the file 
    }

    // just for test
    echo $images. $img.".png <br>";
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="<?php echo $details . $i;?>.php">
          <img src="images/<?php echo $img;?>.png" alt="<?php echo $i;?>">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

bytheway, I just make your code working but there is completely better way for do that

Comment: I will try your code, but I can't change the file name, it is also to be used in others..

Comment: **completely better way for do that** suggest me for that

Comment: for example you can store in database with file name and sorting

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but I am not fully treated with MySQL. So it will take lots of time.

Comment: print this <?php echo $images;?><?php echo $img;?>.png in the loop after IF-ELSE statement

Comment: and the images in that path existing?

Comment: do you see the result is correct? it is 1 2c 3c 4 5c is wrong just the path

Comment: is normal... try to replace $images = "/downloads/vf/images/"; with $images = "/images/";

Comment: I can't they are linked with other files too, and if I do it will be big load of changing codes in all other files.

Comment: ok, I will try..! for now I have to be offline. I will be commenting later with the new edit. Thanks to co operating me!

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work for you.
It will check if the filename exist as a number and echo it, then see if it exists as a "c" image and echo it.
I have not added all the HTML as I'm typing this on my phone, but you should be able to see the "concept of the answer".

```
For($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    $imgC =  $i . "c";

    if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$images.$i.".png")){
        //Echo image 
    }
    if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$images.$imgC.".png")){
        //Echo imageC
    }

}
```